# Pandas df calculate values matching other column in order of appeareance

Tags: python, pandas, loops

Dear stackoverflowers,

I', trying to filter a df with this structure:

```
products=['banana', 'egg', 'cream', 'flour', 'water', 'juice']
bought=['flour', 'water', 'juice', 'banana', 'egg', 'cream']
overview=pd.DataFrame(products, bought, columns=['to buy'])
```

I need to find out whether the products in the column 'to buy' are already bought. I consider them as bought when they already appeared in the column 'products' before, but not after the evaluated row. So as the result, only 'banana, egg, cream' should stay in df.

A loop? Or a rolling window? Please help! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `.apply()` where you check if you've already seen the product (you can use `set` for this task):

```
products=['banana', 'egg', 'cream', 'flour', 'water', 'juice']
bought=['flour', 'water', 'juice', 'banana', 'egg', 'cream']
overview=pd.DataFrame(products, bought, columns=['to buy']) 

seen = set()

def fn(x):
    if x['to buy'] in seen:
        return
    seen.add(x.name)
    return x['to buy']

print( overview[~overview.apply(fn, axis=1 ).isnull()] )
```

Prints:

```
       to buy
flour  banana
water     egg
juice   cream
```